# Using Caliburn.Micro and MahApps in a WPF app. Confused @ MaterialDesignInXaml Documentation to integrate it with MahApps

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro, material-design-in-xaml

I understand what's happening with MahApps and Caliburn; I am trying to add `MaterialDesign.Themes` (or `MaterialDesign.MahApps` package) and color package. The following section from MaterialDesign Documentation makes no sense to me. What am I supposed to do with this? I tried a lot of different things but it's totally missing me.

Here's [the link](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/MahApps.Metro-integration#the-colors/)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary700}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush2" Color="{DynamicResource Primary400}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush3" Color="{DynamicResource Primary300}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush4" Color="{DynamicResource Primary200}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowTitleColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary700}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentSelectedColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBrush" EndPoint="0.001,0.5" StartPoint="1.002,0.5">
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Primary700}" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Primary300}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckmarkFill" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RightArrowFill" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IdealForegroundColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IdealForegroundDisabledBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}" Opacity="0.4"/>
```

It's the Primary### part of the code that's throwing me off. I tried to replace it with

```
HighlightColor => Primary700
AccentColor => Primary500
AccentColor2 => Primary400
AccentColor3 => Primary300
AccentColor4 => Primary200
IdealForegroundColor => Primary500Foreground
```

But even that does not help. If I'm supposed to go and replace those names in a particular Xml dictionary where do I find it? This is such a simple step that's wasted so much time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

What this snippet is doing, is telling the MahApps controls to use your Material Design palette(which is constituted from a primary colour, with multiple hues, and a single accent colour).

The full example is here (from one of the demos in the Material Design source):

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MahMaterialDragablzMashUp/App.xaml

You don't need to replace anything.  So long as you are using a Material Design palette, this just instructs MahApps controls to use that palette.

Comment: Yah I understood that from reading the documentation. What confused me was this line in particular..." you can't just redefine the 'helper' colors as previously defined Material Design colors and be done with it, you'll need to manually substitute the 'Color' attribute of each Brush."

Comment: But I still can't get it to work. I even created a new project. Added nuget pkg for Caliburn.Micro+Mahapp+MaterialDesign+MaterialDesign.MahApps+Dragablz. Then I copy paste the ResourceDictionary from the xaml file you link to and I stioo get an error on  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.MahApps.Defaults.xaml "/>

Comment: Ok sorry for this whole confusion. I think I found the problem. It had something to do with MahApps version. I had installed the latest pre-release version 1.3.### but once I went back down to 1.2.4 which is the latest stable version it all worked. If you do know what caused this and how to avoid such things in future let me know.